# What (if any) are the current models of e-readers with good pdf text reflow?

Tags: pdf, hardware

I've had my [I-river Story HD](https://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/Iriver_Story_HD) for ages (I think since 2013 or something), but I managed to damage the screen by dropping it, and now it's basically unreadable with all sorts of black lines going across the screen. I've started looking for a new e-reader, but the *one* thing I absolutely loved about my old one is how it handled the automatic text reflow of .pdf files. No matter how much I zoomed/increased font size, the text would always neatly reflow. Back then, I bought it specifically because of that, as I would be using it to read scientific articles on the train while going through university.

I'm borrowing my mom's Kobo aura H2O for now, but while the product specifications say it does support .pdf files, there is no mention of pdf text reflow specifically. And I can confirm the reflow simply does not work as well as I'm used to. It's specifically bad with scientific articles, for example. Something that my old e-reader handled without a problem.

I've tried finding a second-hand I-river, but I've had no luck at all, so I've started looking for a new e-reader. I've gone through several popular and big Dutch (and some international) online shops, and none list 'pdf text reflow' as a specification for the e-readers they're selling. I've visited a store in person as well, and the employee there couldn't tell me if there were still e-readers being made with pdf text reflow. Only that some e-readers say they will handle .pdf files, but he couldn't tell me how well they would handle it. Searching Google for "E-reader with pdf reflow" only gives results that are years old, the most recent being from 2019. Questions on this site about e-readers, pdf files and scientific papers are also years old, or suggest jailbreaking e-readers to install third-party software. I'd rather not buy a new e-reader and then have to jailbreak it immediately, so:

Are there still e-readers being made that specifically offer/focus on good pdf re-flow? If so, which models?

Comment: Reflow of PDF text is problematic, particularly for mathematical and scientific text, where a formula may occupy multiple line. "PDF" is derived form *Page Description Format*, i.e., describing how the entire page should be displayed, with hard line-breaks and other formatting built into the file. Some PDF's are mostly images, impossible to reflow without OCR.